# Cannot redraw points which have been set to NULL

Tags: c#, .net, teechart

I have the following setup:

A TeeChart control with a Colorgrid, and a Points Series added to it:

```
grid = tChart2.Series[0] as Steema.TeeChart.Styles.ColorGrid;
points = tChart2.Series[1] as Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Points;
```

To init them, I do:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 128; j++)
    {
        grid.Add(j, rnd.Next(255), i);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    double x = rnd.Next();
    double y = rnd.Next();
    points.Add(x, y);
}

tChart2.Refresh();
```

And then I have a button on my form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 128; j++)
        {
            grid.YValues[j + 128 * i] = rnd.Next(255);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        points.SetNull(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rnd.Next(20); i++)
    {
        points.XValues[i] = rnd.Next(128);
        points.YValues[i] = rnd.Next(128);
    }

    points.BeginUpdate();
    points.EndUpdate();
}
```

But the points do not get drawn. When I remove the for-loop containing the SetNull() statement, then they do get drawn, but I want to be able to clear the points (or hide the points don't want to be seen) without using the Points.Clear()/Points.Add(x, y) methodology.

I've also tried each of the following, but there's no difference.

```
points.TreatNulls = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.TreatNullsStyle.DoNotPaint;
points.TreatNulls = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.TreatNullsStyle.Ignore;
points.TreatNulls = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.TreatNullsStyle.Skip;
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem is caused when you set null all of points. You must know if you use method SetNull the point color is set transparent to make invisible the point. Therefore, if you want solve your problem you only need reset the colors of points you want visible, doing SetNull again or change the points color manually and combining the operation with TreatNullsStyle set to Ignore. In my opinion, I think the best option is use SetNull again as I do in next code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeChart();
    }
    Steema.TeeChart.Styles.ColorGrid grid; 
    Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Points points;

    private void InitializeChart()
    {
        grid = new ColorGrid(tChart1.Chart);
        points = new Points(tChart1.Chart);
        tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 128; j++)
            {
                grid.Add(i, rnd.Next(255), j);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            double x = rnd.Next(100);
            double y = rnd.Next(100);
            points.Add(x, y);
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 128; j++)
            {
                grid.YValues[j + 128 * i] = rnd.Next(255);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            points.SetNull(i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rnd.Next(20); i++)
        {
            points.XValues[i] = rnd.Next(128);
            points.YValues[i] = rnd.Next(128);
            points.SetNull(i, false);
        }
        points.TreatNulls = TreatNullsStyle.Ignore;
    }
```

Could you tell us if previous code works in correct way for you?

I hope will helps.

Thanks,